# What is the term for external tissue insufficiency due to surgery?

Tags: scar-tissue-scars, plastic-surgery

Please assume a case were a human had a plastic surgery to [revise a scar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scar#Surgery) and the surgeon mistakenly removed a bit too much of external tissue (skin/sub-cutaneous-fat) so the scar has become much smaller but a "sink" or a "submergence" became somewhat evident.

What is the term for external tissue insufficiency after surgery?

Answer (score 2):

To be clear with Surgery Nomenclature, it does not matter how the injury was inflicted.

The term you are seeking is: "***Depressed Cutaneous Scar***". More information [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0190962287701509)(Pay-wall), and [here](https://www.uclahealth.org/vitalsigns/treatment-options-to-minimize-scar-damage).

(Colloquially known as '[icepick scars](https://dermnetnz.org/topics/acne-scarring/)')

**Depressed cutaneous scar treatment**

A common surgical treatment option is known as a [*Subcision*](https://dermnetnz.org/topics/subcision/).

> "...involves sliding a needle under the skin to release scar tissue, accompanied by saline injections to stimulate production of new collagen."

Other forms of treatment include:

- Dermabrasion
- Laser treatment
- Laser-assisted drug delivery

[More information here](https://www.uclahealth.org/vitalsigns/treatment-options-to-minimize-scar-damage).